# Complex number roots of unity proof

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

Suppose $w_1$, $w_2$, ..., $w_{n-1}$ are the complex roots not equal to $1$ of $z^n-1=0$, where $n$ is odd.

Show: $\frac{1-\bar{w}}{1+w}+\frac{1-w}{1+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$.

Hello, I am struggling with this complex number proof. Any help is welcomed; thank you in advance.

I have tried expanding the LHS and comparing it to the RHS but am not able to make them equal; I got this far:
$\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$

Part 2 of the question:
Hence show: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1-\bar{w_k}}{1+w_k} = n$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you cross-multiply to clear denominators and expand both sides? What is $w\overline w$ if $w$ is a root of unity?

Comment: Yes. I guess I should have mentioned my attempt at the question.

Comment: You know how I got this far: $\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$; if I was to multiply both sides of the equation by the denominator, the LHS would equal the RHS. Is this an OK proof then?

Comment: The identity also works for $w=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\omega$ lies on the unit circle, more generally, let $\omega = \cos \theta + i\sin\theta$ and $\overline{\omega} = \cos \theta-i\sin\theta$:

$$\text{LHS} = \frac{2-\omega^2-\overline{\omega}^2}{2+\omega+\overline{\omega}}$$
$$= \frac{2 - (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta + 2i \cos \theta \sin \theta)-(\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta- 2i\cos \theta \sin \theta)}{2 + 2\cos\theta}$$
$$= \frac{2 + 2\sin^2 \theta- 2 \cos^2 \theta}{2 + 2 \cos \theta} = \frac{1 + (1 - \cos^2 \theta) - \cos^2 \theta}{1 + \cos \theta} = \frac{2(1 + \cos \theta)(1 - \cos \theta)}{1 + \cos \theta} = 2 - 2 \cos \theta$$
$$= 2 - (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) - (\cos \theta - i \sin \theta) = 2 - \omega - \overline{\omega} = \text{RHS}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $n$ is odd we know: $w\ne-1$.
Therefore, using $(1+w)(1+\bar w)\ne0$ and $w\bar w=1$:
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{1-\bar{w}}{1+w}+\frac{1-w}{1+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}\\
\iff&\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}\\
\iff&2-w^2-\bar{w}^2=2-w^2-\bar{w}^2,
\end{align}$$
the latter equation being obvious identity.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that any root of unity complies $w\bar{w}=1$ and the main manipulation trick you need is:
$$
(w+\bar{w})^2 = w^2 + 2w\bar{w} + \bar{w}^2 = 2 + w^2+\bar{w}^2
$$
so that $2-w^2-\bar{w}^2 = 2 - (w^2+\bar{w}^2) = 2 - ( (w+\bar{w})^2-2 ) = 2^2-(w+\bar{w})^2 $
which is a difference of squares. Can you fill the remaining details?

Comment: I strongly disagree with your initial comment. It is perfectly valid to multiply both sides of an equation by the same number, provided it is nonzero.

Comment: Well, it is ok to multiply both sides of any equation, provided you have one. My point was that you don't know (yet) if $\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$ is true, since that is something you want to prove.If you knew it, then the proof would be complete without any other argument, right? But I get your point, I added a little more information to what I meant in my answer. Thanks,

Comment: The proof principle is "if $c\ne 0$ then $a=b\iff ac=bc$" and you prove the second identity.

Comment: What is $a=b$ in this case? is it $\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$? then I agree that if $\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$ then $(\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}})c=(2-w-\bar{w})c$ for $c\neq 0$. But you first need to prove $\frac{2-w^2-\bar{w}^2}{2+w+\bar{w}}=2-w-\bar{w}$ then. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah! I get it, the if and only if part. Sure, I now agree with you. Thanks @YvesDaoust. I deleted the first part of the answer, since it is clearly not correct.

Answer (score 0):

From $w^n=1$ we deduce $\bar w^n=1$ and $(w\bar w)^n=1$. Then as $w\bar w$ is real and $n$ is odd, $w\bar w=\sqrt[n]1=1$.

The given identity holds for $w=1$. Now assuming $w\ne1$, we multiply both sides of the equation by $(1+w)(1+\bar w)=2-w-\bar w\ne0$ and get

$$2-w^2-\bar w^2=4-w^2-2w\bar w-\bar w^2,$$ which completes the proof.